# the autoincrement primary key duplicate when insert in mysql

Tags: mysql, duplicates, auto-increment

I have a question in my job.There is  a table which the engine is innodb,it has some records already.when I truncate it,and insert data into it.It always occur the error that the primary key duplicate,and i am sure the table is truncated.So anyone can give me some answers.

Comment: Truncating a table will reset the auto increment to 1. Where are you getting this error?

Comment: The new data you are inserting would seem to have duplicated primary keys.